# Touchpad features not working (Ubuntu 14.04 - Asus notebook)

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, asus

as from title I'm having some problems with the features of my laptop's (Asus F556UJ XX020T) touchpad.
I'm new to Ubuntu (14.04LTS is the version I'm using) and this is the result of cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:22/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Asus WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=asus-nb-wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=80000 0 800000000000 0 0 a1606f00900000 8200027800501000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=0401 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-6/i2c-ELAN1000:00/0018:04F3:0401.0001/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0bda Product=57b5 Version=0012
N: Name="USB Camera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

This is the result of xinput --list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I hope I didn't make too many mistakes and that I gave you what you needed to help me, if I didn't I'll try to provide asap. 
Thanks in advance and have a good day.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: And which "features" do not work?

Comment: Scrolling is the on I noticed the most, also I was trying to disable touchpad while typing using syndaemon and it wasn't working at all; it's like my system doesn't recognize it properly.

Comment: So what is the kernel version?

Comment: 4.2.0-34-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This touchpad is fully supported by Ubuntu kernel 4.4.

It can be installed by runing

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

But beware that if you are using a proprietary video driver, it may not build with that kernel without insalling gcc 4.9+. That is not very simple for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: So what course of action would you suggest?
The notebook I'm using has an nvidia geforce 920M.

Comment: There was a question somewhere how to install gcc-4.9 to Ubuntu. You can find that question, update gcc, then install the new kernel.

Comment: I don't have anything against, per say, Ubuntu 15.10 I just thought it would've been better to start with the LTS version, if you think that would make things easier I'm open to reinstall it.  Anyway, thank you very much for your help, is accepting your answer enough or should I do anything more?

Comment: 15.10 will not change anything. It has the same kernel as you have now. In 16.04 it will work out of the box. But it is buggy yet.

Comment: So i just both updated gcc and then updated the kernel and after a reboot I have no cursor at all. I tried reloading ppsmouse with modprobe but it didn't do anything.

Comment: What does xinput show now? And did nvidia driver compile OK?

Comment: When I wrote you I still hadn't installed NVIDIA drivers because it wasn't giving me any problem; I was now trying to install them by this guide:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-nvidia-346-35-ubuntu-1404/
but when I access command console it is filled with automatic messagnes and I can't seem to do much...
I feel really stupid but I can't seem to reach a fully working Ubuntu notebook...

Comment: You probably did not install gcc-4.9 correctly. It should be set as dafault gcc. Then you will be able to install video drivers. And you can always revert all you done by booting with a previous kernel.

Comment: I should have added that the mouse is now working as intended, that's a silver lining. 
When I enter command console it is filled with "PCIe Bus Error: severity=corrected, type =physical layer [...]" lines, do you have any idea what could be causing them?

Comment: The nvidia driver is not installed. That is the problem. I had to install gcc from 15.10 repos and a lot of dependent packages to get it build.

Comment: Am I supposed to install it without being able to see what I'm writing then?

Comment: You can boot with a previous kernel. The system should work OK then. That was probably a bad idea for a newbie to try to fix it that way. You can install 16.04-beta2. All will work out the box. It is an LTS too. But still with some annoying bugs.

Comment: I'll try that then, sorry if I bothered you; I'm taking the free LinuxFoundationX course to learn something but I still know nothing about how to fix this technical issues.  Again, have a good day.